# Difference between simplex and simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

First I know the definition of simplex intuitively as follows,

Simplex is a generalization of the notion of a triangle or tetrahedron to arbitrary dimension.

And 
the defintion of [simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) as follows from wiki, 
Simplicial complex is a toplogical space of certain kind, constructed by gluing together points, line segements, triangles and their $n-$ dimensional counterparts.

**Here what i want to know the difference between two object (simplex and simplicial complex).**

For my short knowledge, I found some statement in the textbook.

Finite simplicial complexes is consisted of a finite number of simplicies.

It seems to me simplex is key object and simplicial complex is a set of this key object.

But i am not sure.

Comment: The way you cut out six squares in a cross-formation (like [this](http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/4/41/Make-a-Paper-Cube-Step-5.jpg/550px-Make-a-Paper-Cube-Step-5.jpg)) and fold and glue them together to make a cube, you can cut out simplices and glue them together along their edges to make a simplicial complex. This gets more difficult to imagine the higher the dimensions are, but the idea is the same.

Comment: A simplex is to a simplicial complex as  a Lego brick is to a dinosaur assembled from such bricks.

Comment: To Arthur, and Georges Elencwajg, Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *simplicial complex* is made out of *simplicies* which I'm sure you already now. But the conditions that these simplices have create the desired topological and algebraic structure.

You can think of a simplicial complex simply (haha) as a set of sets. with certain conditions.
Let $X$ be a set with simplices $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_n$. The following must apply for $X$ to be a simplicial complex:

1. If $\sigma_i,\sigma_j \in X$ then $\sigma_i \cap \sigma_j \in X$. Meaning that simplices only intersect at their faces and
2. If $\sigma \in X$ then if $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ then $\tau \in X$. Meaning that all faces of a simplex are also simplices.

This is the definition for an *abstract simplicial complex*, there are more rigorous definitions for mapping them into $\mathbb{R}^n$ but this I think it the most useful definition for gaining intuitive understanding of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, simplicies are building blocks. Simplicial complexes are "things" constructed from simplicies.